# Python Unit testing - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, json, unit-testing

Im currently trying to unittest a python application for an assignment however I keep getting the above error for all of my tests involving this code block. The same bit of code works for other members parts.

```
columns = ['id', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']
values = [(1, 33, 1, 1, 1)]
json = {columns[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(columns))}
```

In mysql each column is int(11) if that could affect it.

Comment: `Value` and `Column` need to have the same number of values

Comment: your values variable has only one member which is a list of 5 int! so values[i] can not go further than 0

Comment: @Iman add an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your values variable has only one member which is a list of 5 int! so `values[i]` can not go further than values[0]
you can change values variable to list of 5 int like this:

```
values = [1, 33, 1, 1, 1]
```

or change it to tuple of 5 int like this:

```
values = (1, 33, 1, 1, 1)
```

or you can don't change your values variable and make it happened like this:

```
json = {columns[i]: values[0][i] for i in range(len(columns))}
```

with `values[0][i]` you will reach each of list integers

your IndexError can be solve!

Answer (score 2):

change `values` to

```
values = (1, 33, 1, 1, 1)
```

or

```
json = {columns[i]: values[0][i] for i in range(len(columns))}
```